# automate user action on some other app's screen

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

How can an app/service be created which can automate user action on some other app's screen.. 
user action :
 1. clicking a button
 2. filling a textbox with pre specified string
 3. select from dropdown.
I know the way using UIautomation adb tool, but I want that my code automates these user actions on some other app screen by itself.

Answer (score 1):

**UiAutomator** tests can span multiple apps: This type of test verifies the correct behavior of interactions between different user apps or between user apps and system apps. For example, you might want to test that your camera app shares images correctly with a 3rd-party social media app, or with the default Android Photos app. UI testing frameworks that support cross-app interactions, such as UI Automator, allow you to create tests for such scenarios.

Alternatively, if you want to automate your test generation from a UI, you can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).
There are [some videos](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/11/culebra-magical-drag.html) showing how culebra can be used for that.

Comment: Interesting! Any update on the tools since 2015?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public which covers some other use cases